# How I can describe $v^{\perp}$ as $Rw$?

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $v=(\alpha , \beta)\in \mathbb{R}^2$ be nonzero. Describe $v^{\perp}$ as R$w$ for a suitable $w$.

I am thinking to consider the orthogonal complement, and the plane must have an equation of the form $ax+by+cz=0$, This one should be perpendicular to the basis vectors.

But how?

Comment: That plane is a plane in $\Bbb R^3$, whereas you are working on $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: vectors perpendicular to $(\alpha,\beta)$ will be multiples of $(-\beta,\alpha)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are looking for a rotation matrix in the subspace of 2 by 2 that transforms the vector $v$ into another vector rotated by $\pi/2$. Ergo, $u=Rv$ where $u$ is perpendicular to $v$. Following the comment of Tanner you can set up $(-\beta \ \alpha)' = R \: (\alpha \ \beta)'$ where the apostrophes means transpose. The components of the matrix are $R_{11}=0$, $R_{12}=-1$, $R_{21}=1$ and $R_{22}=0$. You can normalize $u$ to get a basis for the orthogonal space (say $v$ perp. in your post).